# Remove character limit in VS Code PHPDebug

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

When debugging in PHP and using the variables pane on the left, there is a limit to the amount of characters you can see for that variable/object when hovering over.

Is there anyway to see the full payload for that variable or any work around other than having to use `file_put_contents` every time I want to see a large variable value? Also printing the variable to the debug console has the same limitation but adds one extra character (lucky me).

Comment: You should probably file an issue on the extension for this, but it's probably a limitation somewhere else and not an arbitrary limit.

Answer (score 31):

In order to achieve that you need to make a change in your **launch.json** configuration of xdebug in VS Code.

The piece of configuration you will need to add to your configuration of `launch.json` is `"xdebugSettings": { "max_data": -1 }`

A simple configuration should look like that

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/myapp/",
        "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
        "xdebugSettings": {
            "max_data": -1
        }
    }]
}
```

`xdebugSettings.max_data`
Controls the maximum string length that is shown when variables are displayed. To disable any limitation, use -1 as value.

Good luck.

Comment: With value of -1 my xDebug just froze and was not able to display any variables. I tried value of 8192 (totally arbitrary) and then it worked.

Comment: @BigBob Yes of course. `-1` will remove any limitation and that could slow down when debugging huge variables. So choosing an arbitrary number would improve speed. A smaller number means better performance as `xDebug` doesn't have to present any variable that is huge. It will cut it's content to the size you have specified by the arbitrary number.

Comment: +1. Still the popup showing when hovering over variables is cut short. If only there were a way to know that it has been cut off or not.

Comment: @Jonny I hope you've since found a solution, however, if your IDE has a debug terminal you should be able to enter the variable into the terminal and get its full value.

Comment: This is the correct option just the WRONG value.-1 slows the debugging process with all variables... for me at least.

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr For me, the debug console seems to have the same character limit as when hovering over a variable. I upped the limit to 100,000, and I can see the full variable in both places now.