# Selenium - Why is the value of driver.page_source only parsing correctly when written to a file?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Using Python, I would like to get the full HTML code from reddit.com to search for strings, however I'm only able to get a weird small version of it. The code in the if statement below *does not* run but it should because I know the string exists on the full page source (string found in both the browser dev tools and the 'View page Source' browser feature):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.reddit.com')
driver.add_cookie({'name':'reddit_session', 'value':'###session cookie value goes here###', 'path':'/', 'domain':'reddit.com'})
driver.refresh() # refresh the page to apply the cookie
source_html = driver.page_source

if 'user account' in source_html:
  print("String found.")

driver.close()
```

[Here is `sourceHTML` copy and pasted into a file. It is 65,536 bytes long and doesn't make sense.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8eTX.png)

What does work is writing the variable contents to a file:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.reddit.com')
driver.add_cookie({'name':'reddit_session', 'value':'###session cookie value goes here###', 'path':'/', 'domain':'reddit.com'})
driver.refresh() # refresh the page to apply the cookie
source_html = driver.page_source

with open('page.html', 'w') as myfile:
   myfile.write(source_html)

driver.close()
```

[And here is the 580,000 bytes of HTML that I am expecting that was written to the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N4Hm.png)

I need be able to search through this HTML within Python and not have to create a file.

I have tried the following without success:

- Whilst debugging, copying the string returned from `driver.page_source`, pasting it into notepad and saving as .html file.
- Using BeautifulSoup to parse the `sourceHtml` variable.
- Executing Javascript to get the entire DOM: `getDOM = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')`
- Using `time.sleep(5)` to wait for the page to finish loading before running `driver.page_source` (although Webdriver waits for the full response anyway before calling back).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Selenium is designed to navigate the DOM.  Why not use webdriver calls?  (No need for .page_source... it's already there in the browser...)

Comment: @pcalkins Reddit is not the only website I want to search strings in so I can't be targetting specific elements. I wanted to use the Requests library to get the HTML but even with that I get the same short response from Reddit.

Comment: I looked at the page and only found User account menu instead of user account.

Comment: Use this instead
if 'User account' in source_html:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

[Copying a variable's value in debug mode does not give you the full value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si9Kn.png)

The string in my `if` statement was also meant to be '**U**ser account' not '**u**ser account' so it was evaluating to `false`.

When I was saving the variable value through debug mode as an html file, it was a fraction of what the variable was actually holding. The limit of these debug variable values varies between developer environments (Netbeans, Eclipse, VS Code etc).  In VS Code it seems to be 65,536 bytes (2^16).

I left this next step alone, but if you do want to change the debug variable size limit, I think there is a 'key:value' that you add to the `launch.json` file (depending on what language you're debugging). [This is how to do it for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634654/remove-character-limit-in-vs-code-phpdebug).

The `launch.json` file applies settings when you 'launch' into debug mode. There is a blue button in that file called 'Add configuration...'. It will list all the settings you can apply to the file.